# GridBaglyout fill does not resize components inside container

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have `JFrame` containing two panels.

The first panel(`jpanel1`) has a welcome message.

The second panel(`jpanel2`) has a `JTable` enclosed in `JScrollPane`.

Whenever the `JFrame` is resized, i want the `JTable` to use the extra space.

I had used `GridBagLayout` to achieve this

`c.gridx=0`, `c.gridy=0` for the `jpanel1`

`c.gridx=0`, `c.gridy=1`, `c.fill=BOTH` for the `jpanel2`.

I see that `jpanel2` grows when frame size is increased.

What needs to be done to increase scrollpane and table size whenever `jpanel2` size is increased.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Change the layout manager for `jpanel2` to use a `BorderLayout`...

Answer (score 2):

Problems with your `LayoutManager`'s.

1. Use `BorderLayout` for `jpanel2` as suggested by MadProgrammer, for resizing `JScrollPane` inside `jpanel2`.
2. With `c.fill=BOTH` you need to use `c.weightx = 1;c.weighty = 1;` to specify how much additional space need grab by component. Read [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx).

Here is example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("P1"));
        p1.add(new JLabel("test"));

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("P2"));

        p2.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(2,2)));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        add(p1,c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        add(p2,c);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```